# Ряд Тейлора "Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции"

Tags: c++

> Ума не дам как это сделать. Написал немного бреда, исправте меня
>   пожалуйста.

Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы значения функции, заданной с помощью ряда Тейлора, на интервале от xнач до xкон с шагом dx с точностью ε. Таблицу снабдить заголовком и шапкой. Каждая строка должна содержать значение аргумента, значение функции и количество просуммированных членов ряда.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
double x, xmin, xmax, dx, eps;
cout << "Input x:"; //Ввод значения x
cin >> x;

cout << "Введите xmin:";
cin >> xmin;

cout << "Введите xmax:";
cin >> xmax;

cout << "Введите шаг dx:";
cin >> dx;

cout << "Введите точность eps:";
cin >> eps;

bool done = true; // признак достижения точности
double ch = x, y = ch; // первый член ряда и начальное значение суммы

for (int n = 0; fabs(ch) > eps; n++) {
    ch *= 1 - (4 * x) + 9 * pow(x, 2) - 16 * pow(x, 3) + 25 * pow(x, 4) - 36 * pow(x, 5); // очередной член ряда  1-4x+9x^2-16x^3+25x^4-36^x5
    y += ch; // добавление члена ряда к сумме
    if (n > xmax) {
        cout << "\nРяд Расходится!";
        done = false; break;
    }
}
if (done) cout << "\nЗначение функции: " << y << " Для x = " << x << endl;


system("pause");
}
```